# jQuery draggable fluid position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery draggable to manipulate multiple items. Here is my code:

```
  options = {
      snap: true,
      distance: 10,
      stop: function() {
          var left = (100 * parseFloat($(this).position().left / parseFloat($(this).parent().width()))) + "%";
          var top = (100 * parseFloat($(this).position().top / parseFloat($(this).parent().height()))) + "%";
          $(this).css({
              left: left,
              top: top
          });
      }
  };

  $("#content").draggable(options);
```

Since using percentage for position, I want to be able keep items visible regardless of screen size.

The above works fine for most part. The problem I'm having is when resizing window, items go out of viewing area.

Since I cant use `$(window).resize(function(){...})`

I need to calculate positions automatically. I'm thinking if more than 50% of item is within left side of container use css left, otherwize use css right position, the same goes for top and bottom.

My problem is I dont know how to calculate those. Any help would be appreciated.